# product convert to polynomial to obtain derivative

Tags: derivatives, products

Supposing we have a function like

$$\prod_{n=0}^{5} \frac{(x+n)}{(1+n)}$$

and want to obtain the derivative at x = 0

Is it valid to convert to a polynomial form

$$\ \frac{x^6}{720}+\frac{x^5}{48}+\frac{17 x^4}{144}+\frac{5 x^3}{16}+\frac{137 x^2}{360}+\frac{x}{6} $$

and then obtain the derivative

$$\ \frac{x^5}{120}+\frac{5 x^4}{48}+\frac{17 x^3}{36}+\frac{15 x^2}{16}+\frac{137 x}{180}+\frac{1}{6} $$

so that we can substitute x = 0 and the result is 1/6 ?

Comment: Yes, this is valid.

Comment: does this mean that for the same function if the upper number was 99 that the result  at x = 0 would be 1/100?

Comment: Yes, if you take the product up to $n=N$ the answer would bye $\frac 1 {N+1}$.

Comment: However, if you want to do it for any upper bound $N$, expanding will no longer work, so you need a different idea; there are rules for the derivative of a product ;)